# Is there any equivalent sliding-buffer chan in golang?

Tags: go, clojure

In clojure we can have sliding-buffer chan; Is there any equivalent in golang?

```clj
(require '[clojure.core.async :refer [go-loop <! >!! sliding-buffer chan]])
(def sliding-chan (chan (sliding-buffer 1)))
(go-loop []
  (println "Received:" (<! sliding-chan))
  (recur))
(dotimes [n 100]
  (>!! sliding-chan n))

;;=> Received: 0 
;;=> Received: 99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Go has [buffered channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) but they will block when the channel is full.

You'll probably have to write something yourself, maybe with a goroutine in the middle that manages the buffer (maybe using [deque](https://github.com/tebeka/deque) ;)